# How to write a superclass field to a file if it is an object

Tags: java

My subclass implements `Serializable`, but my superclass does not.
Both subclass and superclass contain variables that need to be saved as part of the state of the subclass.
I made copies of the superclass fields, but with the `Engine` field, I don't know what to do. It does not write to the file. Tried some methods, but they did not work, now I do not know what to do.

```java
class Vehicle {                                                                   
    int speed;                                                                    
    Engine engine;                                                                
    int productionYear;                                                           
                                                                                  
    public Vehicle(int speed, Engine engine, int productionYear) {                
        this.speed = speed;                                                       
        this.engine = engine;                                                     
        this.productionYear = productionYear;                                     
    }                                                                             
                                                                                  
    public Vehicle() {                                                            
    }                                                                             
}
```

```java
class Plane extends Vehicle implements Serializable {                             
    String model;                                                                 
    int flightRange;                                                              
    transient Chassis chassis;                                                    
    int speedCopy;                                                                
    transient Engine engineCopy;                                                  
    int productionYearCopy;                                                       
                                                                                  
    public Plane(int speed, Engine engine, int productionYear, String model, int flightRange, Chassis chassis) {
        super(speed, engine, productionYear);                                     
        this.model = model;                                                       
        this.flightRange = flightRange;                                           
        this.chassis = chassis;                                                   
    }                                                                             
                                                                                  
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream) {             
        try {                                                                     
            objectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject();                              
            objectOutputStream.writeInt(chassis.numberOfWheels);                  
            objectOutputStream.writeInt(chassis.wheel.diameter);                  
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(chassis.wheel.load);                   
        } catch (Exception e) {                                                   
            e.printStackTrace();                                                  
        }                                                                         
    }                                                                             
                                                                                  
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) {                
        try {                                                                     
            objectInputStream.defaultReadObject();                                
            int numberOfWheels = objectInputStream.readInt();                     
            int diameter = objectInputStream.readInt();                           
            String load = (String) objectInputStream.readObject();                
            this.chassis = new Chassis(new Wheel(load, diameter), numberOfWheels);                                
        } catch (Exception e) {                                                   
            e.printStackTrace();                                                  
        }
    }
}
```

Create and add object to list.

```java
List<Plane> planes = new ArrayList<>();
planes.add(new Plane(350, new Engine("Electrical", 120), 2002,               
        "ATR 74", 1800, new Chassis(new Wheel("Reinforcement", 6), 12)));    
planes.add(new Plane(460, new Engine("Electrical", 100), 1997,               
        "ATR 72", 1700, new Chassis(new Wheel("Subgrade", 7), 10)));         
planes.add(new Plane(520, new Engine("Electrical", 170), 2010,               
        "ATR 42‑500", 2000, new Chassis(new Wheel("Reinforcement", 9), 13)));
```

Write object to File.

```java
public static void writeObject(File file, List<? extends Vehicle> object) {                         
    try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)))
        object.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(value -> value.productionYear));                        
                                                                                                    
        object.forEach(value -> {                                                                   
            try {                                                                                   
                final Class<? extends Vehicle> aClass = value.getClass();                           
                if (aClass.getSimpleName().equals("Plane")) {                                       
                    Plane plane = (Plane) value;                                                    
                    plane.speedCopy = plane.speed;                                                  
                    plane.productionYearCopy = plane.productionYear;                                
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(plane);                                          
                } else {                                                                            
                    Ship ship = (Ship) value;                                                       
                    ship.speedCopy = ship.speed;                                                    
                    ship.productionYearCopy = ship.productionYear;                                  
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(ship);                                           
                }                                                                                   
            } catch (IOException e) {                                                               
                e.printStackTrace();                                                                
            }                                                                                       
        });                                                                                         
        objectOutputStream.flush();                                                                 
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                         
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                        
    }                                                                                               
}
```

Comment: What does not get saved into a file and which kind of file are you generating?

Comment: Engine field superclass, I write in the .txt file

Comment: Can you please add the code that you use to create and save the objects into the file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From doc :

> Serialization: At the time of serialization, if any instance variable is inheriting from non-serializable superclass, then JVM ignores original value of that instance variable and save default value to the file.

It means in your case, that the variables `speed`, `engine` and `productionYear` will be set to their default value that you define in the `Vehicule` constructor without args (Since you define nothing, the default values are 0, null and 0). I think it's because the variable is null that you do not see it in the file.

You do not use the engineCopy in your code. Maybe it should be better to implements the Serializable interface at the `Vehicule` level ..

By the way, classes designed for inherirance should rarely implement Serializable (as well as interfaces should rarely extends it)